# How to add space inside multicolumn text

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, multicol

I've below latex code for creating cheat sheets.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}% Packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % For header and footer
\usepackage{multicol}           % Allows multicols in tables
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Intelligent column widths
\usepackage{tabulary}           % Used in header and footer
\usepackage{hhline}             % Border under tables
\usepackage{graphicx}           % For images
\usepackage{xcolor}             % For hex colours
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % For unicode character support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Without this we get weird character replacements
\usepackage{colortbl}           % For coloured tables
\usepackage{setspace}           % For line height
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Needed for total page number
\usepackage{seqsplit}           % Splits long words.
%\usepackage{opensans}          % Can't make this work so far. Shame. Would be lovely.
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     % For underlining links
% Most of the following are not required for the majority
% of cheat sheets but are needed for some symbol support.
\usepackage{amsmath}            % Symbols
\usepackage{MnSymbol}           % Symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}            % Symbols
\usepackage{pythontex}
%\usepackage[english,german,french,spanish,italian]{babel}              % Languages% Document Info
\author{mkpeacock}
\pdfinfo{
    /Title (ZIO cheatsheet.pdf)
    /Creator (Cheatography)
    /Author (rnatarajan)
    /Subject (ZIO Cheat Sheet)
}% Lengths and widths
\addtolength{\textwidth}{6cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-3cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2cm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm} % Space between columns
\setlength{\headsep}{-12pt} % Reduce space between header and content
\setlength{\headheight}{85pt} % If less, LaTeX automatically increases it
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header line
\renewcommand{\seqinsert}{\ifmmode\allowbreak\else\-\fi} % Hyphens in seqsplit
% This two commands together give roughly
% the right line height in the tables
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\onehalfspacing% Commands
\newcommand{\SetRowColor}[1]{\noalign{\gdef\RowColorName{#1}}\rowcolor{\RowColorName}} % Shortcut for row colour
\newcommand{\mymulticolumn}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{>{\columncolor{\RowColorName}}#2}{#3}} % For coloured multi-cols
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}} % New column types for ragged-right paragraph columns
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline} % Required as custom column type in use% Font and Colours
\definecolor{HeadBackground}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{FootBackground}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{TextColor}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{DarkBackground}{HTML}{17629C}
\definecolor{LightBackground}{HTML}{F0F5F8}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\color{TextColor}% Header and Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % Set header to blank
\fancyfoot{} % Set footer to blank
\fancyhead[L]{
    \noindent
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{tabulary}{5.8cm}{C}
            \SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
            \vspace{-7pt}
            {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\noindent
                    \hspace*{-6pt}\includegraphics[width=5.8cm]{navbar_brand.png}}
            }
        \end{tabulary}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tabulary}{11cm}{L}
            \vspace{-2pt}\large{\bf{\textcolor{DarkBackground}{\textrm{ZIO Cheat Sheet}}}} \\
            \normalsize{by \textcolor{DarkBackground}{mkpeacock}}
        \end{tabulary}
\end{multicols}}\fancyfoot[L]{ \footnotesize
    \noindent
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{tabulary}{5.8cm}{LL}
            \SetRowColor{FootBackground}
            \mymulticolumn{2}{p{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Cheatographer}}  \\
            \vspace{-2pt}rnatarajan \\
            \uline{github.com/rajcspsg} \\
        \end{tabulary}
        \vfill
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tabulary}{5.8cm}{L}
            \SetRowColor{FootBackground}
            \mymulticolumn{1}{p{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Cheat Sheet}}  \\
            \vspace{-2pt}Published 25th July, 2022.\\
            Updated 13th May, 2022.\\
            Page {\thepage} of \pageref{LastPage}.
        \end{tabulary}
        \vfill
        \columnbreak
        \begin{tabulary}{5.8cm}{L}
            \SetRowColor{FootBackground}
            \mymulticolumn{1}{p{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Sponsor}}  \\
            \SetRowColor{white}
            \vspace{-5pt}
            %\includegraphics[width=48px,height=48px]{dave.jpeg}
            Measure your website readability!\\
            www.readability-score.com
        \end{tabulary}
\end{multicols}}\begin{document}
    \raggedright
    \raggedcolumns% Set font size to small. Switch to any value
    % from this page to resize cheat sheet text:
    % www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_169.html
    \footnotesize % Small font.
    \begin{multicols*}{3}
        \begin{tabularx}{5.377cm}{X}
            \SetRowColor{DarkBackground}
            \mymulticolumn{1}{x{5.377cm}}{\bf\textcolor{white}{Classes and Objects}}  \tn
            \SetRowColor{white}
            \mymulticolumn{1}{x{5.377cm}}{class SomeClass \{ \newline % Row Count 1 (+ 1)
                private \$property;  \newline % Row Count 2 (+ 1)
                ~~~~public \$anotherProperty;  \newline % Row Count 3 (+ 1)
                ~~~~protected \$yetAnotherProperty = null;  \newline % Row Count 5 (+ 2)
                ~~~~public function \seqsplit{\_\_construct(\$arg=null)}  \newline % Row Count 7 (+ 2)
                \{ \newline % Row Count 8 (+ 1)
                ~~~~\$this-\textgreater{}property = \$arg; \newline % Row Count 9 (+ 1)
                \} \newline % Row Count 10 (+ 1)
                public function someMethod()  \newline % Row Count 11 (+ 1)
                \{ \newline % Row Count 12 (+ 1)
                ~~~~echo "Hi"; \newline % Row Count 13 (+ 1)
                \} \newline % Row Count 14 (+ 1)
                public function getProperty() \newline % Row Count 15 (+ 1)
                \{ \newline % Row Count 16 (+ 1)
                ~~~~return \$this-\textgreater{}property; \newline % Row Count 17 (+ 1)
                \} \newline % Row Count 18 (+ 1)
                public function setProperty( \$p ) \newline % Row Count 19 (+ 1)
                \{ \newline % Row Count 20 (+ 1)
                ~~~~\$this-\textgreater{}property = \$p; \newline % Row Count 21 (+ 1)
                \} \newline % Row Count 22 (+ 1)
                \} \newline % Row Count 23 (+ 1)
                \$myObject = new SomeClass( "123" ); \newline % Row Count 24 (+ 1)
                echo \$myObject-\textgreater{}getProperty(); // 123 \newline % Row Count 25 (+ 1)
                \$myObject-\textgreater{}property; // ERROR:private% Row Count 26 (+ 1)
            } \tn
            \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{DarkBackground}}-}
        \end{tabularx}
        
        \par\addvspace{1.3em}% That's all folks
\end{multicols*}\end{document}
```

I want to add space in the code inside the multi column.

For example,  the line `private $property;` I want to have 4 space from the border compared to the previous line.

I tried `\tab`, `quad`,  `\hspace{1cm}` etc none of which are working.

Any idea how can i achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\hspace*{1cm}`, that should work.

Assuming you will be using this more often, try creating a command instead.

```
\newcommand\indentcode{\hspace*{1cm}}
```